# Jquery in Rails project not working in production, but is working in development

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, cloud9-ide

I have been looking on the internet and trying different things out for days (including many similar questions on this), but I still yet to find an answer.

I am hosting on heroku and using cloud9 for development (in rails).  On development everything works well.  It seems on production that the normal javascript is working, but the jquery code is not working.  I can not figured out what is going on. I will post below some code that may be of use. I am sure it is likely a simple fix that I am just overlooking.

I have precompiled assets then add them to git. The javascript works and updates when I do this, it is just the jquery that is not  working at all.

I do not know if it has anything to do with bootstrap either.

Really, I appreciate any help or pointers so much.

Here is the errors in the javascript console:
[Javascript console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/532Z9.png)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .

/* global $ */
```

Here is my production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Attempt to read encrypted secrets from `config/secrets.yml.enc`.
  # Requires an encryption key in `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]` or
  # `config/secrets.yml.key`.
  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?


  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "project_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

end
```

Gem File

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'

end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]


gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'devise'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
end
```

Comment: What do you mean "jQuery is not working"? Is `$` not defined when you check in console?

Comment: did you tried asset precompile before pushing to heroku?

Comment: @MahabubIslamPrio Yes, I have done this many times.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I added this piece of test    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
             if (jQuery) {  
               // jQuery is loaded  
               alert("Yeah!");
             } else {
               // jQuery is not loaded
               alert("Doesn't Work");
             }
          });
        </script>                                                                                                             it comes up as "Yeah" on production, that it is working, but none of the jquery code is being implemented on the production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'r error states that `Popper` is not defined. A look into the `bootstrap-rubygem` docs reavals that you have to require popper before you require `bootstrap-sprockets` like this:

```
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

I think thats your issue. If you don't define your dependencies right then `assets:precompile` does not collect all needed files and your css and js does not work in production.

Answer (score 0):

In your assets/javascript/application.js
code should look like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```